# Doubts regarding 方がより

Tags: grammar

> それならどちらか一人に絞って魔力を提供した**方がより効率的**という訳か。
>
> If that is the case, Squeezing magic in one of them end supplying would be more effective.

I think it means:  This way is more effective.

Am i right?

This got me confused with

より and 方が.

Could someone give me an explanation of 方がより?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「Phrase + [方]{ほう}が + より + Adjective」
>
> = "(Phrase) is more (adjective)"

So, your undestanding of 「～～方がより[効率的]{こうりつてき}」 is correct.  It means "~~ is more effective".

Though I am not sure if this is what is confusing you, I will go ahead and state that there are two different 「より's」 used in statements of comparison.

> 「より」 the ***adverb***:

This is the 「より」 used in  「～～方が**より**効果的」.  It means "more" and it modifies adjectives.  One could also safely say that this 「より」 is used like a more formal version of 「もっと」.

> 「より」 the ***particle***:

This is the 「より」 used in a sentence like 「[富士山]{ふじさん}は[東京]{とうきょう}タワー**より**[高]{たか}い。」= "Mt. Fuji is taller than Tokyo Tower."

「Topic + は + (Base/Standard of Comparison) + **より** + Adjective」

Though I have never studied Japanese as a foreign language, I am pretty sure that the particle 「より」 is the first 「より」 that is taught in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language.  ⇒ 「AはB**より**～～だ/です。」